# Is it possible to create this style without using a wrapper?

Tags: html, css

Nobel Prize to anyone who can help me out with this.

I need to create the following style:

[image]

**Constraints:** Can only use `CSS`. That field is generated as an `h3` tag by the content management system. Cannot write `HTML` to place it inside a wrapper. Would prefer not to use a background image since the client has not given me one. Cannot to resort to `JavaScript` because this style needs to apply to multiple pages and I don't have a global `JavaScript` file in the environment I'm using.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d7qrLLug/

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using css borders:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d7qrLLug/9/)

```
h3 {
    color: #FFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #423025;
    padding: 5px;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    border-style: double;
    border-width:4px;   
    border-left: none;
    border-left: none;
}
```

Comment: Good, but please note that this will increase the height of the element by 8 pixels.

Comment: Can fix that by changing the top and bottom padding to 1px instead of 5px.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using before and after pseudo elements.

```
h3:before, h3:after {
border-top: solid 1px white;
content: "";
display: block;
}
```

See this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/d7qrLLug/5/

Answer (score 2):

That's actually very simple:

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/d7qrLLug/11/

```
h3 {
    color: #FFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #423025;
    padding: 5px;
    position:relative;
}
h3:before {
    position:absolute;
    top: 3px;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    content:" ";
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}
h3:after {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 3px;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    content:" ";
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

**Note:** You need absolute positioning on `:before` and `:after` to not change the original height of the produced `h3` element, if that isn't important, this will do the job:

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/d7qrLLug/12/

```
h3:before,
h3:after {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    content:"";
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}
```